# How to create Pagination in Promoted Links in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, promoted-links

I am using Promoted Links list in SharePoint 2013, now I know how to wrap the images to bring them horizontally but is there any way to add pagination if user have 200 images.
I don't want to show every image in same page. Also I didn't like the OOTB slider comes with promoted link tiles view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing same using SharePoint Designer,

1. Add Data view to the page
2. Add Promoted link list as data source to that Data View
3. From Options add pagination to view as per no of items needed on the page

I have not implemented the same but you can try and let me know if that works.

Also you can go through this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.everything-about-promoted-links-in-sharepoint-2013-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx), you might find something helpful

Comment: Can you provide some details because it didn't work for me. Would be great if you can try for me.

Comment: can u share XSL code, that would speed up process for me

Comment: What I understand Promoted Links uses sp.ui.tileview.js file which makes the view to come up in one row.Using CSS or JQuery code, I am able to render the page with multiple tiles but I have more than 500 tiles to create and I need pagination for this ( like the normal pagination for custom list)

Comment: I have gone through the blog using JQuery, it does not have anything related to pagination like normal list where SP uses clienttemplates.js to render the data.

Can you suggest something where I can simply add JavaScript using script editor or content editor web part and get pagination down the page.I want to show 5 tiles in one row and 4 total rows on 1 page.

Comment: <XmlDefinition>
<View Name="{######}" Type="HTML" ReadOnly="TRUE" OrderedView="TRUE" DisplayName="Tiles" Url="/sites//Lists/Icon Image List Promoted Links/Tiles.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="TRUE"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Title"/><FieldRef Name="BackgroundImageLocation"/><FieldRef Name="Description"/><FieldRef Name="LinkLocation"/><FieldRef Name="LaunchBehavior"/>

Comment: <FieldRef Name="BackgroundImageClusterX"/><FieldRef Name="BackgroundImageClusterY"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><JSLink>sp.ui.tileview.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>

Comment: @RishabhShukla : I tried to implement what i had suggested and yes things does not work. You can not add pagination and filtering to Promoted links webpart using Designer and also you can not use promoted links as data source for data view. 
You can use customizations or Scripts to achieve the same...